# How do I copy one list to another that has an object with additional properties in C# ? (without a foreach)

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the need to copy one list of objects into another, however, the second list has additional properties (basically, the first list is a subset of the second list).
Here's an example of how to do with a foreach loop for a class Product and another class ProductExt that inherits from product and adds another property to it.
-- this is an abbreviated version of what I need to do --

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //note there are 78 more product properties!
}

public class ProductExt : Product
{
    public int FirstVariantId { get; set; }
}
```

And an example of how it's done with a foreach (but I'd like to do this in Linq but not really sure how to go about it):

```
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 1, Name = "widget a" });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 2, Name = "widget b" });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 3, Name = "widget c" });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 4, Name = "widget d" });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 5, Name = "widget e" });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 6, Name = "widget f" });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 7, Name = "widget g" });

        List<ProductExt> productExts = new List<ProductExt>();
        
        // want to  copy products into productExts list with a default value of 0 for FirstVariantId
       foreach(var p in products)
        {
            var px = new ProductExt();
            px.Id = p.Id;
            px.Name = p.Name;
            px.FirstVariantId = 0;
            productExts.Add(px);
        }
```

Is there a way to do this in Linq (with the default value)?

Comment: Does it have to be a list of ProductExt? A product list can still hold any type inheriting.

Comment: `products.Select(x=>new ProductExt{....});`

Comment: Any reason for the "without foreach" constraint? LINQ isn't magic, it does the same work.

Comment: ``px.FirstVariantId= p.Id -1;`` LINQ is not that magic, it makes it easy but it still does loop too!

Comment: I was looking for something less verbose, actually.  It's not really for speed, just ease (I've dozens of classes to add extended properties too - and no access to the source, but can inherit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) for these type of work. The benefit would be that you wouldn't need to remember mapping new properties if you add new ones later.

---

### Create a singleton mapper that you can access from your classes and methods, usually this is done on application startup

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { 
    cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductExt>();
 });
 var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

---

### Then

```
List<ProductExt> productExts = products.Select(p => mapper.Map(p, new ProductExt())).ToList();
```

Comment: This does not magically assign values to the "new" properties

Comment: @LegacyCode what do you mean? it's a mapper, it maps all the property values with the same name to target new object. The only different property here is "FirstVariantId", which will end up being 0, which is already what question owner wants it to be.

Comment: Well... What if he wants FirstVariantId to be 4 or -1? I know... you can just `mapper.Map(p, new ProductExt{ FirstVariantId = -1  })`... But I think you should show that in the code. But why use a slow mapper though? I would understand, when you use Mapster, but not slow AutoMapper.

Comment: @LegacyCode you can do that way yeah.. and also there are more configuration options before creating a mapper that you can easily set another default value than zero.. say that, that extra property "FirstVariantId " was something to calculate from source object.. you could do that in configuration and tell it while mapping set its value to this.. Yeah, AutoMapper, Mapster, whatever.. the point is using a mapper not to map manually every propery one by one every time it is needed..

Comment: This solves the problem of verbosity so I picked this as the answer. What an awesome utility - never heard of it before!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to try Mapster, next. (I was thinking of rolling my own, but why reinvent the wheel?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
List<ProductExt> productExts = products.select(product=> new ProductExt()
    {
        Name = product.Name,    
        // another properties
    }).Tolist();
```

If you don't assign value to any property, the default value set to that property . ( Example : For int properties => 0 )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like Mapster is the winner here - it's very fast and simple.

```
        List<ProductExt> productExts = new List<ProductExt>();
        products.Adapt(productExts);
```